# Can't shutdown in 13.10

Tags: shutdown

[image: error while shutting down]

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.10 but my laptop can't shutdown. When I try to shutdown it will just keep loading endlessly. After pressing a non-letter key on the keyboard I'm transferred to a screen which shows a error.

When my laptop is showing this error I can still power it off by the on/off button.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: You seem to have made up the error message since you could not copy paste it while it was shutting down, please post a photo of the error when you can't copy-paste or screenshot it, but don't make up the error message; it doesn't help.

Comment: Some laptops just have problems shutting down when using kernels newer than 3.8. My HP laptop has the same problem. No idea how to fix it myself.

Comment: @DanJohansen check if WOL is active in BIOS. If so turn it of and try shutdown again ;) Same for user268850 btw.

Comment: I wonder if sudo poweroff can fix your problem... My netbook often refuses to shut down when I log in guest mode. So I have to use this command line to "convince" it to shut down.